# How do I specify a link to a folder with translations? i18next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, translation, i18next

[I tried this way but it didn't work out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmbNj.png)

[how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2hl0.png)

[structure photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kL8NI.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.